# How to tell boss I will look for other projects/customers?

Tags: job-change

Some background for the question:
I started in a startup a couple of months ago because I thought it might be an interesting place to work. I accepted a huge salary decrease (more than 50%) because I was really bored of working on big projects where the only interesting part was the money.

Now the investors are holding back money because of lack of trust in the "external team" that have failed to deliver over and over again. This has resulted in contract cancellation with the external team and the investors have set some requirements that need to be met within 4 months before they will invest more money into the company. The boss have asked everybody if they can afford a reduced salary during the 4 months and I have accepted it with some conditions.

At the same time there are some "red flags" in how things are run and I've partly lost the confident that we will be able to deliver and I don't believe it was the "external team" that failed to deliver - but bad project management.

Based on this I'm thinking of going back to work as consultant again, but that means I need to go out in the market again and find clients. Part of what I will do is online marketing/advertisement. My main target audience will be people like the boss and the investors.

So to the question:
How can I tell my boss and the investors that they might see ads where I'm promoting my services? I only want to tell them because I think it's better to tell it before/if they see it.

Comment: Do you have any obligations, legal or contractual, to inform your boss of side jobs you do? Would they be done for potential competitors?

Comment: It sounds like you no longer trust the company's management style. So, if there is no contractual agreement that keeps you at this company, then, maybe, it is a better option for you to quit this company completely, and go back to your freelance job full time ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 while guessing slightly, I imagine the poster is trying to avoid the gap in their income that comes between leaving their current employment and getting new contracting work.

Comment: @nvoigt no to your questions.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 The easiest way out is just to quit, but I dont want to leave a mess that will just make it even more dificult for them to deliver the requirements (its a small place and big chance to meet the people in other settings). I just want to cover my as* in case there wont be any more investments, but at the same time dont make it look like I'm not loyal anymore and just sticking around till I find something else.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I wouldn't say anything. Your employer has cut your salary - your boss is (should be!) well aware that people will be looking for other opportunities. If they do ask, just say "With the uncertainty about the future, I'm just covering my bases".

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, advertising your services as a consultant, whilst still in full-time employment, is a bad idea; it will cast doubt on your commitment to your employer, which won't look good to anyone who doesn't know the details of your situation. At worst it may get you fired for violating the terms of your contract, which also doesn't look good.

I understand you aren't currently in a good place, and you want to start exploring other options, but still you need to study the fine print in your employment contract. If management are looking to deflect criticism of what they've done, they could make you a scapegoat for the things that are currently going wrong in the company. You could find yourself (very unjustly) being blamed for the current failures, which would make it difficult to get any contract work, due to negative reports from your ex-employer.